# Program which triggers buttons combination

Tags: keyboard-events

Recently I have had second thoughts about the program which triggers combination of buttons ( e.g ctrl + v) when running.

Does anyone have an idea how to write such a program?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Have you written something already and are wondering if it's efficient or have you done nothing?

Comment: Actually I'm a dispatcher with just a newbie knowledge of programming. I have no idea how to even start. I was trying to find a solution on c/c++ forums but with no result. It would be wonderful to have such a program to refresh my pick up board every ten second. :) I would try to create something if there would be kind of point to start with.

Comment: I have a general view of how I want it to look. I know how to create a loop which would satisfy the conditions.. but i have no idea how to execute buttons combination idiopathicly?